# Starting eclipse in Tomcat - Debug Mode - Timeout Error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, debugging

I get the following timeout error when trying to start tomcat in eclipse.

Timeout waiting for Tomcat v5.5 Server at localhost to start. Server did not start after 45s.

Does anyone know hot to set the tomcat timeout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In server view, dbl-click on the server.  The server configuration editor opens.  There is a Timeouts section within.

Comment: Thanks buddy... it worked. However in older versions they do not have the timeout option.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to "Windows"-->"Preferences"--> click on "Server" then you will see drop down "Server timeout delay". Select Longer.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove all breakpoints unnecessary and run again.